# SP13 - Cannot add user as farm administrator

Tags: 2013, groups, user

As a farm administrator am I not allowed to add an other farm administrator?
If I fill in the existing user and hit apply I get following...

> Sorry, something went wrong 
>   An unexpected error has occurred.
>   Correlation ID: 01c9b69c-f8ec-e0be-9915-f6e3717a17d0

What's wrong?

Comment: can you goto the 15hive log folder and try again to reproduce the error, then in log folder open the most uptodate file (txt) and search for the correlation id, then update your question with the error that is generated

Answer (score 3):

If your account is not in Local admin on the Server then even with farm Administrator rights you cannot add another user in the same group.

In Simple words, Add your account into Local Admin group on the server(especially Central Admin Server), then try it.

this is old KB but still applicable for your situation.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/926320

If above not solve the issue, then you can check the ULS for the correlation id(mentioned in your error).

Comment: Thanks but the user I want to add is a local admin.

Comment: ok, what about the user under which you login? that login should be in local admin

Comment: My user is a local admin too.

Comment: Run the browser as Administrator? if you are on server try to access central admin from PC? also check the uls logs for the more detail about the error, you can search for correclation id mentioned in your error message....or user user merge-splogfile to get

Answer (score 3):

your account is not part of the local admin group on the server. If you look up the error from the correlation id give on you 15hive log directory i think you would see the following:

> Local administrator privilege is required to update the Farm
>   Administrators' group

goto server manager -> expand configuration -> expand local user and groups -> click on groups folder -> on the right hand side you should now see a list of local groups for the server, topmost you should see administrators -> double click administrators group -> a popup will appear -> click on add button -> search for your account to add to this group and click apply and then ok.

you should then be able to add users to admin group.

or

you can save this ps code to run in powershell,

```
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell -erroraction SilentlyContinue 

# Creates a new Farm Administrator

$newFarmAdministrator = Read-Host -Prompt 'Please provide the name of the new Farm Administrator in the form of DOMAIN\Username'

$caWebApp = Get-SPWebApplication -IncludeCentralAdministration | where-object {$_.DisplayName -eq "SharePoint Central Administration v5"} 
$caSite = $caWebApp.Sites[0] 
$caWeb = $caSite.RootWeb

$farmAdministrators = $caWeb.SiteGroups["Farm Administrators"] 
$farmAdministrators.AddUser($newFarmAdministrator, "", $newFarmAdministrator, "Configured via PowerShell")

$caWeb.Dispose() 
$caSite.Dispose()

$caDB = Get-SPContentDatabase -WebApplication $caWebApp 
Add-SPShellAdmin -Database $caDB -Username $newFarmAdministrator
```

when you run the .ps1 file it will promt you with the following message:

> provide the name of the new Farm Administrator in the form of
>   DOMAIN\Username

all you need todo it write to powershell the user domain\name e.g. myDomAin\ali.sharepoint

http://www.sharepoint-reference.com/Blog/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=12

Comment: I'm on a Windows Server 2012 R2. I don't find the path you described. In the server manager I don't see the `expand configuration -> expand local user and groups ->`
My user is added to the administrator group in the computer management.

I didn't execute the powershell code yet.

Comment: The powershell code doesn't work for me...
`Get-SPWebApplication : Cannot access the local farm. Verify that the local farm is properly configured, currently available, and that you 
have the appropriate permissions to access the database before trying again.`

Comment: I got it now. I manually added the user to the **WSS_ADMIN_WPG**-Group. Now I am able to add users as Farm Administrators in the Central Administration of SharePoint 2013.

Comment: glad to see you got it working, the ps script does that, you need to run the console as admin first ;), that would run it as administrator that is part of wss_admin_wpg!

Comment: Tried again but then it gave me this...
`Exception calling "AddUser" with "4" argument(s): "The user does not exist or is not unique."`

Comment: try this instead Add-SPShellAdmin -UserName CONTOSO\User1
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ff607596(v=office.15).aspx

Comment: I updated my script to -match instead of -eq and remove "v5" to account for other versions (or names) of sharepoint ca

Answer (score 2):

You have to do it in Internet Explorer AND run it as an administrator or it fails every time. Even in SharePoint 2016. 
So if you set your prefered browser to Chrome and run Central Administration via Central Administration Link on Start Menu (or via Find.. function) it is going to fail..
Just copy the url from there to IE in admin mode and off you go..

We are all sure they are going to fix it in the next release..

Answer (score 1):

If the farm administrator has been added to the local administrator group, and the problem persists, attempt to open the Central Administration by using the Central Administration Link on the Start Menu.

Ensure you open it as an administrator or log in as a different user, providing the farm account used to configure SharePoint during the installation via the SharePoint Configuration wizard.

[image]

> You can also check the same scenario at this [link](https://spgeeks.devoworx.com/local-administrator-privilege-is-required-to-update-the-farm-administrators-group/)